# laravel Undefined table: 7 ERROR:

Tags: postgresql, pdo, laravel-5.5

I am working on a new laravel 5.5 site and am getting an exception I don't understand when the application tries to connect to a Postgresql database.

All settings in my env file are correct for the database connection

I am creating the table with a migration and when I run php artisan migrate the table gets created.

Under /app I have a file NbnCo.php that contains

```
class NbnCo extends Model
{

    protected $fillable=[

// All the db table fields are here

];
}
```

Under /app/Http/Controllers I have NbnCoController.php

It contains

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\NbnCo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class NbnCoController extends Controller
{
    public function showForm()
   {
        return view('upload');
   }

public function store(Request $request)
{   
    //get file
    $upload=$request->file('upload-file');

    $filePath=$upload->getRealPath();

    //open and read
    $file=fopen($filePath, 'r');

    $header= fgetcsv($file);

    $processedHeader=[];
    //validate
    foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
        $lheader=strtolower($value);
        array_push($processedHeader, $lheader);
    }

    while($columns=fgetcsv($file))
    {
        if($columns[0]=="")
        {
            continue;
        }

        $data=array_combine($processedHeader, $columns);

        // Table update
        $nbn_location_identifier=$data['nbn_location_identifier'];
        // the rest of the folumns follow the same style

        $nbn = NbnCo::firstOrNew(['nbn_location_identifier'=>$nbn_location_identifier]);
        // the rest are added in the same way

        $nbn->save();
     }

   }
}
```

The idea is that a simple form is displayed and a CSV file is selected to be uploaded into the nbnco table in the nbn database.

I am getting 2 PDO errors

```
PDOException in Connection.php line 337:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "nbn_cos" does not 
exist
LINE 1: select * from "nbn_cos" where ("nbn_location_identifier" = $...
^
```

and

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "nbn_cos" does not 
exist
LINE 1: select * from "nbn_cos" where ("nbn_location_identifier" = $...
^ (SQL: select * from "nbn_cos" where ("nbn_location_identifier" = 
LOC000012257222) limit 1)
```

I do not understand where the nbn_cos table that laravel is trying to connect to is coming from. I also don't understand where the nbn_cos relation is coming from.

The best I can find is that I am doing something wrong with the naming of my classes and the name of the database table. I can't work out, even with a lot of Google searching, where the database table name is actually passed to the connection and SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel and Postgres requires the table to be included in the model, and the table name.

`protected $table = 'database.table';`

So, if your database is called `test` and the table is `nbnco`, it will look something like:

`protected $table = 'test.nbnco'`